# No Array.filter() in Rhino?

Tags: javascript, rhino

Why can't I use `Array.filter()` in Rhino?

The code is like this:

```
var simple_reason = ["a", "b", "c"];
print(typeof simple_reason.filter);

var not_so_simple_reason = new Array("a", "b", "c");
print(typeof not_so_simple_reason.filter);
```

Both cases output "undefined".

Comment: What version of Rhino are you using? When I run it in 1.7 I get "function" for both cases (they are exactly equivalent by the way, unless you change Array).

Comment: When you start it interactively (i.e. without a file to run) it should print the version when it starts.

Comment: `Rhino 1.5 release 4 2003 01 16` - pretty old

Comment: I'll update it now, hopefully get speed boost also :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>There is no standardized `filter` function for Javascript Arrays, it is only an extension to the standard.</s> *(There is as of the ES5 spec published just a month after this answer was posted.)* The [MDC reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/filter) gives you an compatibility sample to use for those implementations that do not support it...

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array();
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
      {
        var val = this[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't know `filter` wasn't part of standard.

Comment: Yes, but it _is_ part of Rhino because Rhino implements __JavaScript__, the language maintained by Mozilla, not ECMAScript. The person who asked the question must be using an outdated version of Rhino.

Answer (score 4):

You are using an outdated version of Rhino that does not implement JavaScript 1.6. Try [Rhino 1.7](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/download.html).

Answer (score 1):

Is filter standard javascript? It is only in Mozilla since 1.8 (or so [this reference](http://www.dannyg.com/ref/jsquickref.html) tells me)